# WPF animation is applied to ALL controls not just one I need

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, eventtrigger

I wanted to animate text inside of a `TextBlock` control.

I did something like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tboxStatusComment" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding StatusComment, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Foreground="{StaticResource LightBlay}">                            
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="tboxStatusComment" RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="blinkAnimation"/>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

and in the Resource...

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="animRed" Color="Red"/>
    <Storyboard x:Key="blinkAnimation" Duration="0:0:1" >
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="tboxStatusComment" 
                        From="{StaticResource LightBlayColor}" 
                        To="{Binding Source={StaticResource animRed}, Path=Color}" 
                        AutoReverse="True" 
                        Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    </Storyboard>
```

The Animation *is* playing, it triggered when text changes, however the problem is that ALL of the `TextBoxes` in `Window` are Animated, not just one I want.

What am I doing wrong??

**EDIT:**
I've moved animation to code behind.

In my property:

```
private string _StatusComment;
public string StatusComment
{
    get { return _StatusComment; }
    set 
    { 
        _StatusComment = value;
        AnimateText();
        OnPropertyChanged("StatusComment"); 
    }
}
```

and in code behind:

```
private void AnimateText()
{
    Color lightblaycolor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFE0E0E8");
    SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(lightblaycolor);
    tboxStatusComment.Foreground = brush;
    ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation(lightblaycolor, Colors.Red, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
    animation.AutoReverse = true;            
    brush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
}
```

Comment: Why would the animation be applied to any other `TextBlock`? It isn't using the code you have posted. Your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Additionally your posted code shouldn't even compile I guess. Your EventTrigger looks quite odd.

Comment: @mm8 Animation IS applied to every `TextBlock`. Why? That is what I'm asking. Situation doesn't make much sense not my question.

Comment: @BionicCode Code is compiling and running. Just because something "looks quite odd" doesn't mean it is bad. Try ti yourself. Beside, I fail to see how your comment is helpful.

Comment: @IvanMilijic: Copy the code yoy have posted into a new project and try it out yourself :)

Comment: @mm8 OK. Now, this IS strange. Same code works in one app and acting crazy in other. I abandoned idea of setting animation in `XAML` and did it in code behind. In the `get` part of my property I added call to method `AnimateText()